# Need to dynamically update a value in a PHP associative array using AJAX without updating other values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, associative-array

I'm creating a cart page using PHP. I have managed to store the items that the person wants to buy in a session variable which stores an associative array that has the identifier of the item as the key and the quantity of the items as the value:

```
if (isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])){
        $_SESSION["cart"][$isbn] += 1;
    header("Location:cart.php");
}
```

I also managed to list these items on the cart using a foreach loop and a query:

```
            <?php
            $total;
            foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $product=>$quantity){
                $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE $product LIKE isbn");
                $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $title = $data["title"];
                $price = $data["price"];
                $image = $data["image"];
                $author = $data["author"];
                $isbn = $data["isbn"];
                print 
                "<a href='product.php?product=".$isbn."' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action>
                    <img src='".$image.">
                    <h5>".$title."</h5>
                    <h5>£".$price."</h5>
                </a>
                <select name='quant' id='quant'>
                    <option value=''>".$quantity."</option>
                    <option value='1'>1</option>
                    <option value='2'>2</option>
                    <option value='3'>3</option>
                    <option value='4'>4</option>
                    <option value='5'>5</option>
                    <option value='6'>6</option>
                    <option value='7'>7</option>
                    <option value='8'>8</option>
                    <option value='9'>9</option>
                    <option value='10'>10</option>
                </select>";

                $total += $price*$quantity;
            }
            ?>
```

As you can see, there is a dropdown list that I want to use to modify the number of items purchased. I need this list to update the value of the specific key within the $_SESSION['cart'] variable and then for that quantity to dynamically multiply by the price to display a total. For this, I am using jQuery.

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#quant").change(function(){
                $.get('ajax/getTotal.php',{quant:$(this).val()},function(data){
                    $('#total').load(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I need to know two things:

1. How do I update the values in the SESSION variable without affecting the other values?
2. How do I properly use jQuery to dynamically update the total after the values in the SESSION variable have been updated?

I really appreciate your help. I'm really new to AJAX and I am very lost.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, what you are trying is impossible. PHP is run on the servers building the HTML. After the page is served to the client/browser you cannot manipulate the PHP variable anymore. 
You can [manipulate the HTML using JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp), e.g. to change the value of a DOM Element to show the total. However, this will be only effective on the client side. Using jQuery: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp

To make such a change effective on the server side / the session (which is also handled on the server) as well you will have to send a POST request to your server.

The easiest way for this is a to wrap your isbn and quantity into a normal `<form method="POST" action="/pathToSessionUpdatingScript">`. 
E.g. using an `<input>` field for the isbn and `<select>` for the quantity. If you want to avoid clicking a button you [can submit the form using JS / JQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_submit.asp) using the change event like you did above.

On the server side you then simply [update the session using another php script](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

After that you may [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php) to your original page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. It's very likely I wasn't clear. What I'm looking for is for a way to update the specific value of a specific key inside the $_SESSION variable.